# jQuery append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a slight error with jQuery $([selector]).append(element),

```
var Site_Id = 119;
var iLi = document.createElement("li");
iLi.setAttribute("class", "hidden site_id_"+Site_Id);
iLi.setAttribute("name", "ArticleType["+Site_Id+"]");
console.log(iLi)
$(".level-2 div row_group_off").append(iLi);
```

For some reason the DOMm is throwing an Exception with jQuery calling it

`uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: {path_removed} :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 12" data: no]`

So with that I added the `console.log` that's in my code above I'm getting

`<li class="hidden site_id_151" name="ArticleType[151]">`

this would mean that the element is being created as a very valid HTMLLiElement but for some reason jQuery is unable to append it to my UL `.level-2 div row_group_off`

Comment: what element is `row_group_off` ?

Comment: didn't you forget a dot in front of row_group_off ?

Comment: hard to tell without the html

Comment: @all thanks Stupid misstake that i spent 10 mins looking for lol

Comment: @Martin Barker: What was the _stupid_ mistake that you are not sharing with the public?

Comment: @shef read the answer and the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".level-2 div .row_group_off").append(iLi);
```

Or

```
$(".level-2 div #row_group_off").append(iLi);
```

Or

```
$(".level-2 div.row_group_off").append(iLi);
```

Or

```
$(".level-2 div#row_group_off").append(iLi);
```

Answer (score 3):

First: Why do you mix up vanilla Javascript with jQuery in that way?

I'd go for it, like

```
$('<li>', {
    'class':    'hidden site_id_' + Site_Id,
    'name':     'ArticleType[' + Site_Id + ']'
}).appendTo( '.level-2 div row_group_off' );
```

Of course, `row_group_off` **must** be an `<ul>` element. In the current form, jQuery will try to query a **node** with the name *row_group_off* which hopefully doesn't exist. So you either did forget a `#` or `.` to query for an `id` or `class` -name

Comment: Just to update for Googler's i used createElement as it has been proven to be faster that jQuery using `$("<li>")` by a member on SO so that's is why there mixed better performance so better for browser the as you have got to remeber is that jQuery is Javascript why go though the load of jQuery Selector when you don't need to?